# Book about a crystal-like prison planet

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a book in which the main character was sent to a prison type planet made of crystal. He wakes up with a symbiotic creature plugged into his ear. The creature is able to communicate through plug in. The creature manufactures new crystal parts for the main character to survive, but does it when he's sleeping; such as changing out his eyes and later internal organs.

Read it in the mid 80's, but I think it was written earlier.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Possibly *[Sentenced to Prism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentenced_to_Prism)* by Alan Dean Foster?  Although it really isn't a prison planet, the title makes it sound like it, and all the crystal stuff fits.

Comment: I'd also vote for that being the case. Good book.

Comment: There was some goofy stuff about fractals at the beginning but he dropped it pretty quickly and the book improved greatly.

Comment: The fractal aspect of things never really left... the creatures are all crystal-based, and a recurring theme in the stories is that many surfaces are extremely sharp due to how they're basically blades all the way down. :)

Comment: I'm sure you are correct.  I haven't read it in a long time. I just remember almost stopping reading it because the fractal stuff in the beginning was nonsensical, but I kept on and it got better.