# Man crashes on silicon-based planet

Tags: story-identification

I read this short book  about 1982. I guy crashes on a planet that is all silicon based. He loses his suit and covers himself in a type of armor made from the silicon life forms. I can not remember the name. I think the title has about 5 words. Goes like "The .....on....at....

Comment: Do you mean 6 words? "The X on Y at Z" is 6 words, not 5.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/67115/looking-for-a-book-about-a-crystal-like-prison-planet/67118#67118

Answer (score 8):

*[Sentenced to Prism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentenced_to_Prism)* by Alan Dean Foster is the story of a man sent to the planet of Prism to investigate the loss of a science team. His powerful all-terrain suit is seriously damaged in a run-in with the unusual life-forms of the planet, and he has to learn to survive without it, eventually befriending a member of the local sentient race, whose people replace not only his armor, but eventually quite a lot of his body.